# Point SubDomain to EC2 Instance

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, subdomain

Sorry if this has been answered numerous times, I just cannot seem to get the right thing here.

I have a domain which is still managed at a 3rd party provider (like Godaddy).

`Mysite.com` is pointed with an `A record` to another EC2 instance - this is working fine (I have the public, elastic IP address as value)

I want to get `sub.mysite.com` pointed at a different EC2 instance. I currently have an elastic IP setup for this different EC2 instance. On the 3rd party provider, I have:

sub.mysite.com (as `name`)
14400 (as the `TTL`)
CNAME (as the `record type`)
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx (the value of the amazon ec2 elastic ip of the ec2 instance; as the `value`)

if I access:

```
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

or

```
sub.mysite.com
```

It just fails loading the page.

**Nginx config:**

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name     sub.mysite.com;
        root /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/mysite/myapp;

        access_log /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/mysite/error/access.log;
        error_log /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/mysite/error/error.log warn;
        connection_pool_size 2048;

        fastcgi_buffer_size 4K;
        fastcgi_buffers 64 4k;

        location /static {
            alias /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/mysite/myapp/static/;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_read_timeout 10;
            proxy_connect_timeout 10;
            add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? or is this a propagation issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `CNAME` record can only point to a hostname, not an IP address.  If the destination is an IP address, you need an `A` record.